# using a string that is changed each iteration in a for loop as a name of a vector

Tags: c, loops, memory

I would like to allocate memory using pointers in a loop in c. I have found answers to questions similar but not to this specific problem. 
For example

```
char name_bin[50]; 
for (int i=0; i<NB; i++) {                                                                                                    
  sprintf(name_bin, "bin_vector%d", i);                                                                                      
  double *name_bin = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * NGMAX);                                                             
}
```

I can't seem to find a way of doing this. I want NB arrays of size NGMAX all with different names, bin_vector0 etc 
I was told it was possible and so any help would be very welcome.

Comment: A 2-D array each of size `NGMAX` has different integer names of `0` and `1`  and `2` etc. for the 1-D arrays. But your example code is flawed - you are using same variable name twice within the same scope.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was trying to avoid using 2d arrays but I guess that is the only way to do it..?

Comment: you're trying to create variable names during runtime? There's no way to do that that I'm aware of.

Comment: Oh the variable names are not within the same scope. They have the same name, but the one defined within the scope of the loop takes precedence over the same variable name defined at function scope. Just don't do that, make variable names unique. See how easily they can be confused by the reader, or coder?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a new variable with a name derived at runtime. In C, the way to accomplish that is using a table that associates a string with an object. How the table is implemented is up to you, depending on your requirements and the amount of complexity you are willing to deal with. For small numbers of names, a linked list may be sufficient. For very large numbers of names, you may likely need a tree or a hash table.

However, your particular problem can be resolved with a simple array.

```
double *bin_vector[NB];
```

Then, you can refer to the 6<sup>th</sup> bin with `bin_vector[5]`.

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback. I see what I was trying to do cannot be done so instead I went with the array of pointers and the code looks like this

    double *name_bin[NB];
    for (int i=0; i<NB; i++) name_bin[i] =    (double*)malloc(NGMAX*sizeof(double));

Comment: there should be a * before the 1st name_bin and also one after the 2nd double. The formatting removed them.